# php - Why calling static methods from sibling classes does not work without instantiation?

Tags: php, class, static, parent, siblings

I have a general parent *item* class for database elements, like

```
class item {
    function set($i = '') {
        //set element in database
    }

    function get($id = '') {
        //get element in database
        return $item;
    }
}
```

I have different classes implementing the item's parent, like *users* and *events* - when I call the set method inside users for class events, like

```
class users extends item {
    function dothis() {
        events::set(array('start' => 'today', 'end' => 'tomorrow'));
    }
}
```

it acts as if I wrote

```
class users extends item {
    function dothis() {
        self::set(array('start' => 'today', 'end' => 'tomorrow'));
    }

}
```

*trying to insert the event in the users table*, so I have to instantiate the class this way

```
class users extends item {
    function dothis() {
        $e = new events();
        $e->set(array('start' => 'today', 'end' => 'tomorrow'));
    }

}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a way to avoid the instantiation?

EDIT - All the classes in my framework are called in a static way, without the need of *new* or *$this*, and it works perfectly.

Comment: where is the `event` class?

Comment: If you're trying to call a method in the same class use `$this->get`, the `self::`, `static::` (and more) syntax is for static methods, which `set()` and `get()` are not.

Comment: `All the classes in my framework are called in a static way ... it works perfectly` - blatantly it does not =).

Comment: @MalayMondal actually you make me think that the event class is not include.. do php falls back to self:: if events:: is not found?

Comment: @GiobiFasoli the static keyword is not optional. You are currently ignoring (and possibly aren't even aware?) warnings ala `Non-static method Foo::set() should not be called statically` - turn on error reporting; _always_ develop with E_ALL shown. The code you have not shown in the question `//get element in database` is the bit where the problem is, if you want a specific answer, show some specific code and a specific problem.

Comment: Especially if you're doing a lot of subclassing and inheritance, using only static class calls is pretty much missing the point. It's not that it *can't* work, but it's missing the point of classes and *OOP* entirely. You're just pushing your car instead of actually getting in it and turning on the engine; to trot out a car-related analogy.

Comment: @AD7six you're very right about the problem solution, thank you. The adding to database part is not the problem. I'm fixing code in a production environment, that's what I'm paid for: so I can't have the luxury of E_ALL :\

Comment: Ewww the bad habits/excuses keep on coming. Good luck.

Comment: @deceze I'm not doing a lot of subclassing: it's just item->users - would you suggest an instantiation even in this case?

Comment: @AD7six it's more an _I'm paid for this_ problem, meaning I don't have time to rewrite the framework, but thanks for the head-up and for the solution :)

Comment: I don't really care about you rewriting the code, though recognising the problems you've got and are creating (e.g. I am going to work in production AND won't even trouble myself to read the error log) would be in your interest. I care about you turning the question into something that can be answered - you aren't doing that. The question is missing the code that matters, and doesn't contain an actual problem statement (code I write like this acts like I wrote it like that is _not_ a problem statement it's a guess/interpretation of what's actually happening, and not helpful).

Comment: Classes should always be designed to be instantiated, even if you (currently) plan on only ever making a single instance of it. OOP is about decoupling code. Without instantiation, it's just a regular collection of static function calls.

Comment: @AD7six sorry I did not get your advice: I corrected the subject to be an answerable question, I hope it fits. Thank for the advice, not thanks for the lack of kindness - have a nice day.

Comment: :( You are so missing the point - you can't address my comments by editing the title. *show more code and and an actual problem*. I tried, good luck.

Comment: @deceze the current framework allows the class to be defined with predefined methods (set, get, and so on) for base db rows, and you can implement more methods for each item (users can login, logout, have rank statuses) - it works without instantiation but I just discovered it's a bad practise.

Comment: Yeah, it's bad practice. You might be interested in this: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: @deceze for the record, I'm reading the article and I got the point. I expecially publicly apologize to AD7six for being so rude: you've been more than patient!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use static methods you should also declare your methods like:

```
protected static function set($i = '') {

protected static function get($id = '') {
```

So you are able to call `self::set(...)` and `self::get(...)`.

If you want to use non-static methods you only have to change

```
self::set(...)
```

to

```
$this->set(...)
```

Comment: You're going to get into problems regarding late static binding using `self::` - You should link to the relevant docs in the php manual, no static keywords indicates a rather fundamental misunderstanding/lack-of-knowledge regarding static/instance methods/properties/concepts.

Comment: I know this, but I'm using all implicitly without the need to express protected static. It just fails calling methods implicitly between siblings.